# How to insert and remove a slide before the first slide using jQuery Cycle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Hi im Just wandering how to insert a slide on jquery cycle before the first slide. I have a function that removes the first slide and add the slide before the first slide. Please help.

Comment: refer http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/add3.html

Comment: Thanks Sir, i already read this. But this is not the functionality that im thinking. I have an slideshow application that displays more than 500 images. The problem is that it makes the browser crashed specially on ie. I think the solution to this problem is to cut the previous slides if the number images is greater than 1000 then puts back again if i click the previous.

Comment: but i think jquery cycle not supported that functionality to insert the slide on before the first slide.

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` the elements before carousel init called

Comment: no problem on removing the slide but inserting the  new slide before the first slide i think thats the main problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

use `.append()` to add the slide before first slide.

Comment: i think you should post an example of your work, there might be something else blocking your jQuery methods not performing their function.

Comment: What im thinking is this if i have slides like

1 2 3 4 5 . . . 200

then i want to remove the first 100 slides then the new set are

100 101 102 103 . . . 200

if i click the previous then it will put back the first 100 slides again and insert before 101 so this will be the output_add_rewrite_var

1 2 3 4 5 . . . 100 < 101 102 103 104 . . . 200

this is my solution to avoid the application to hang and can handle even more thousand of images